# CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() without Lambda

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm struggling with the functional style of `Supplier<U>`, etc and creating testable code.

So I have an `InputStream` that is split into chunks which are processed asynchronously, and I want to know when they are all done. To write testable code, I outsource the processing logic to its own `Runnable`:

```java
public class StreamProcessor {
    
    public CompletableFuture<Void> process(InputStream in) {
        List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            try (SizeLimitInputStream chunkStream = new SizeLimitInputStream(in, 100)) {
                byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(chunkStream);
                CompletableFuture<Void> f = CompletableFuture.runAsync(createTask(data));
                futures.add(f);
                
            } catch (EOFException ex) {
                // end of stream reached
                break;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(ex);
            }
        }
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new));
    }
    
    ChunkTask createTask(byte[] data) {
        return new ChunkTask(data);
    }
    
    public class ChunkTask implements Runnable {
        final byte[] data;

        ChunkTask(byte[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // do something
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // checked exceptions must be wrapped
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This works well, but poses two problems:

1. The processing code cannot return anything; it's a `Runnable` after all.
2. Any checked exceptions caught inside `ChunkTask.run()` must be wrapped into a `RuntimeException`. Unwrapping the failed combined `CompletableFuture` returns the `RuntimeException` which *needs to be unwrapped again* to reach the original cause - in contrast to the `IOException`.

So I'm looking for a way to do this with `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`, but I can't figure out how to do this without lambdas (bad to test) or to return a `CompletableFuture.failedFuture()` from the processing logic.

Comment: You can also write a class that implements `Supplier` like you've written one with `Runnable`. Is your question basically how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two approaches:

**1. With `supplyAsync`:**

When using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`, you need a supplier instead of a runnable:

```
    public static class ChunkTask implements Supplier<Object> {
        final byte[] data;

        ChunkTask(byte[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public Object get() {
            Object result = ...;
            // Do something or throw an exception
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync( new ChunkTask( data ) )
    .whenComplete( (result, throwable) -> ... );
```

If an exception happens in `Supplier.get()`, it will b e propagated and you can see it in `CompletableFuture.whenComplete`, `CompletableFuture.handle` or `CompletableFuture.exceptionally`.

**2. Passing a `CompletableFuture` to the thread**

You can pass a `CompletableFuture` to `ChunkTask`:

```
    public class ChunkTask implements Runnable {
        final byte[] data;
        private final CompletableFuture<Object> future;

        ChunkTask(byte[] data, CompletableFuture<Object> future) {
            this.data = data;
            this.future = future;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Object result = null;
                // do something
                future.complete( result );
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                future.completeExceptionally( ex );
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the logic becomes:

```
while (true) {
    CompletableFuture<Object> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
    try (SizeLimitInputStream chunkStream = new SizeLimitInputStream(in, 100)) {
        byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(chunkStream);
        startThread(new ChunkTask(data, f));
        futures.add(f);
     } catch (EOFException ex) {
         // end of stream reached
         break;
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         f.completeExceptionally( ex );
         return f;
     }
}
```

Probably, Number 2 is the one that gives you more flexibility on how to manage the exception.

Comment: Thank you! So simple, I just couldn't see it! Helped me a ton.